# How can I execute a piece of code for a certain amount of time in JavaScript and React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know that the [browser timers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers) exist, but I've never used them and don't know which are the ones that I need to use. 
I'm using React Native and I want a code block to execute only during a 10 second interval, the lower bound of the interval should be when the first click to the button is made. This is what I have:

```
  <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => nClicks++}>

        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
         Tap Here!
        </Text>

        </TouchableHighlight>
```

The action is responding perfectly, for every click the value of the global variable increases by 1. I just need to somehow find a way to add the time interval constraint. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

within the `onPress()` function, you might probably want to put `setInterval()` method. You can try the following code:

```
var SetIntervalMixin = {
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.intervals = [];
  },
  setInterval: function() {
    this.intervals.map(clearInterval);
    this.intervals.push(setInterval.apply(null, arguments));
  }
};

var App = React.createClass({
  mixins: [SetIntervalMixin], // Use the mixin
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      seconds: 0,
      nClicks: 0
    };
  },
  onPress: function( plus ) {
    //this.setState({nClicks: plus});
    this.setInterval(this.codeToExcecute, plus * 1000); // Call a method on the mixin
    this.setState({nClicks: this.state.nClicks + 1});
  },
  codeToExcecute: function() {
    console.log('Im the code to excecute');
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          React has been running for {this.state.seconds} seconds. nClick: { this.state.nClicks }
        </p>
        <button onClick={ this.onPress.bind(null, this.state.nClicks + 1) }>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

The demo: http://jsbin.com/biyibu/2/edit